# Sort descending with timestamp in elasticsearch and then filter the sort with a particular value on top

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I want to sort the data in elastic search using the timestamp.. And in that sorted results i want those matching a particular key on top and then the rest

for eg.. I have a data where there is a key timestamp and gender.
So i want to sort the data in the descending order of the timestamp and the result should contain the gender with male on top and then the rest of the genders.

I tried but can achieve any one at a time
P.S : My elasticsearch version is 1.5

Comment: you need to submit two sort keys

Comment: 'sort' : {
'rating' :{
  'gender'  :{
       'order' =>  'asc' }
 },
  { 
 'timestamp'  :  {
       'created_at'  :   { 'order' :  'desc' }  
}
},

Comment: i dont want to sort the other key... gender is just an example.... there may be other keys where there are multiple values and I want to filter that key having a value on top

Answer (score 0):

You could use a constant score query to give all documents with the desired key the score "1", and all others the score "0".
Then you can sort by score & timestamp.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

You could also do the same with a script, but the function score query would be recommended.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting